# Early Deadline First (EDF) scheduling in real-time systems feasibility test proof

Tags: operating-systems, proof-techniques, scheduling, process-scheduling, real-time

I am trying to prove **Theorem 6.2** on page 127 of the book *Real-Time Systems* by *Jane W. S. Liu*: [http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~thai/books/2000%20_%20Liu-%20Real%20Time%20Systems.pdf](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/%7Ethai/books/2000%20_%20Liu-%20Real%20Time%20Systems.pdf)

It is based on Early Deadline First(EDF) scheduling.

It says the proof is similar to the proof for **Theorem 6.1** on page 124-126. However, I am still stuck.

Here is what I have so far:

Density of task $T_j:\ \delta_j=\frac{e_j}{\min{\left(D_j,p_j\right)}}$

Density of the system: $∆=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\delta_j=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{e_j}{\min{\left(D_j,p_j\right)}}$

$e_j$ is the execution time for task $T_j$

$D_j$ is the deadline for task $T_j$

$p_j$ is the period for task $T_j$

$\emptyset_j$ is the phase for task $T_j$

$r_{j,b}$ is the release time for task $T_j$ at period $b$

$J_{j,b}$ is the job for task $T_j$ at period $b$

$\emptyset_j=r_{j,1}$

$r_{j,b}+p_j=r_{j,b+1}$

**THEOREM 6.2.** *A system $T$ of independent, preemptable tasks can be feasibly scheduled on one processor if its density is equal to or less than $1$.*

If $D_j<p_j$ for some $j$, then $∆=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{e_j}{\min{\left(D_j,p_j\right)}}\le1$ is only a sufficient condition so we can only say that the system may not be schedulable when the condition is not satisfied.

I try to prove the contrapositive just as **Theorem 6.1** on page 124-126. So what I try to prove is that if according to an EDF schedule, the system fails to meet some deadlines, then its density is larger than $1$.

Suppose that the system begins to execute at time $0$. And at time $t$, the job $J_{i,c}$ of task $T_i$ misses its deadline. Assume the case that the current period of every task begins at or after $r_{i,c}$, the release time of the job that misses its deadline. We use $t$ to divide two types of task besides task $T_i$ as in below figure: 1) tasks with deadline happens before $t$ in the current period just like $T_f$, 2) tasks with deadline happens after $t$ in the current period just like $T_k$.

[image]

$J_{i,c}$ misses its deadline at $t$ tells us that any current job whose deadline is after $t$ is not given any processor time to execute before $t$ and that the total processor time required to complete $J_{i,c}$ and all the jobs with deadlines at or before $t$ exceeds the total available time $t$. So we have

$t<\left\lceil\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_i\right)}{p_i}\right\rceil e_i+\sum_{k\neq i,k\neq f}{\left\lfloor\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_k\right)}{p_k}\right\rfloor e}_k+\sum_{f\neq i,f\neq k}{\left\lceil\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_f\right)}{p_f}\right\rceil e}_f$

then

$t<\left\lfloor\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_i\right)}{p_i}\right\rfloor e_i+e_i+\sum_{k\neq i,k\neq f}{\left\lfloor\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_k\right)}{p_k}\right\rfloor e}_k+\sum_{f\neq i,f\neq k}{{\left\lfloor\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_f\right)}{p_f}\right\rfloor e}_f+\sum_{f\neq i,f\neq k}\ e_f}$

And it is

$=\left\lfloor\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_i\right)}{p_i}\right\rfloor e_i+\sum_{k\neq i,k\neq f}{\left\lfloor\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_k\right)}{p_k}\right\rfloor e}_k+\sum_{f\neq i,f\neq k}{{\left\lfloor\frac{\left(t-\emptyset_f\right)}{p_f}\right\rfloor e}_f+\sum_{f\neq k}\ e_f}$

$\le \left(\frac{t}{p_i}\right)e_i+\sum_{k\neq i,k\neq f}{\left(\frac{t}{p_k}\right)e}_k+\sum_{f\neq i,f\neq k}{{\left(\frac{t}{p_f}\right)e}_f+\sum_{f\neq k}\ e_f}$

$=t\sum_{h=1}^{n}\frac{e_h}{p_h}+\sum_{f\neq k}\ e_f$

$\le t\sum_{h=1}^{n}\frac{e_h}{\min{\left(D_h,p_h\right)}}+\sum_{f\neq k}\ e_f$

$=t∆+\sum_{f\neq k}\ e_f$

So I prove up to $t<t∆+\sum_{f\neq k}\ e_f$

but I cannot prove $∆>1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be too focus on the algebra. I believe I only need to argue or proof a scenario that would give the least density of the system that will fail to meet a deadline.
As shown in the figure below, all tasks start at the same time with same period and deadline. For each of period, each task only have time slot D=D1=D2=...=Dn to execute. In other words, they share exactly the same time slot to execute. If density > 1 then obviously schedule will fail. If the below system has a density of $1^+$(greater than 1 by the smallest amount), then any changes on Di or Pi will only increase the density of the system or make the system feasible.

[image]